# How to plot 100% stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, annotations, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

Let's assume I have DataFrame as below;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["Foo", "Foo", "Baar", "Foo", "Baar", "Foo", "Baar", "Baar"], "count_1":[5,10,12,15,20,25,30,35], "count_2" :[100,150,100,25,250,300,400,500]})
```

I may plot the stacked graph as below:

```
df.groupby(['name'])['count_1', 'count_2'].sum().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image: Plot]

Then how can I make the 100% stacked bar graph? This is what I expect:
[image: Plot2]

Also could I get % number as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide after the sum like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['name'])['count_1', 'count_2'].sum())
df = df.divide(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, title='100 % stacked area chart')
```

And to annotate :

```
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(int(p.get_height()*100))+'%', (p.get_x(), p.get_height()))
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to manually calculate your percentages to plot them, then to get the percentages in your bars, you have to iterrate over the rows and add them with `plt.text`:

```
dfg = df.groupby('name').sum()
data = dfg.div(dfg.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100)
data.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(15,9), title='Stacked bar')

for i, v in data.reset_index(drop=True).iterrows():
    for val in v:
        plt.text(i, val/2, str(round(val))+'%', size=12)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]